# Regular Expression Check To See If String Contains All The Same Numbers

Tags: regex, expression

I'm new to regular expressions and for a project I'm working on I was required to validate a field to see if the 10 digit number entered contained all the same numbers.

I found the following solution:

```
([1-9])\\1{9}
```

source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/461871/java/java/Check-if-number-contains-all

I have tried to Google it, but nothing that explains what the expression is doing. I was wondering if someone could explain how this expression works.

Comment: Technically the regex should have only one backslash `([1-9])\1{9}`, your code likely shows two because it's being escaped in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this:

```
([1-9])   // Capture any number 1-9 and store it as the first "capture"
\1        // Substitute the first "capture" as raw text into the regex
{9}       // Match that raw text another 9 times (i.e. 10 in total)
```

Be sure that `0000000000` shouldn't match your expression since this isn't matched by `[1-9]`

Answer (score 1):

It's all about `captured groups`

`([1-9])` is a `capture group` that captures a single digit between 1-9

`\1{9}` is the `first capture group` i.e. ([1-9]) that repeats 9 times..

**EXAMPLE**

you can have a regex that matches content which is always between matching tag names.

So,using this regex

```
<(.*?)>(.*?)<\1>
```

for **each** of the below input

```
<party>At Garden<party>
<dance>With GirlFriend<dance>
<drink>risky<drive>
```

You would capture at group 2

```
At Garden
With GirlFriend
//risky would not match
```